# What episode did Naruto combine Nine-Tails Chakra Mode and Sage Mode?

Tags: naruto

In which episode did Naruto combine Nine-Tails Chakra Mode and Sage Mode?  If possible, how did he know, or who told him to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first part of your question...

> In which episode did Naruto combine Nine-Tails Chakra Mode and Sage Mode?

It's episode 381, or chapter 645.

And the last part...

> If possible, how did he know, or who told him to do so?

It was Kyuubi who told Naruto that he'll let him use Sage Mode while also using his, as in Kyuubi, Chakra Mode.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Sources:

- [Nine-Tails Chakra Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COj2U.jpg)
- [Two Powers...!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTFQZ.jpg)